Flink Kafka connector fetch metadata failed
I am new to flink and i am trying out one job to read data from kafka and write it to clickhouse. For which I am writing java program with kafka as a source. When compiling the code and running it using flink ui. I am getting below error.
org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:219)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailureAndReport(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:166)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.ExecutionFailureHandler.getGlobalFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:140)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleGlobalFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:324)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.coordination.OperatorCoordinatorHolder$LazyInitializedCoordinatorContext.lambda$failJob$0(OperatorCoordinatorHolder.java:669)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.lambda$handleRunAsync$4(PekkoRpcActor.java:460)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleRunAsync(PekkoRpcActor.java:460)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(PekkoRpcActor.java:225)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.FencedPekkoRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedPekkoRpcActor.java:88)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleMessage(PekkoRpcActor.java:174)
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:33)
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:29)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:127)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:126)
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:29)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:175)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:547)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:545)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:229)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:590)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:557)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:280)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:241)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:253)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Global failure triggered by OperatorCoordinator for 'Source: Kafka Source -> Sink: Unnamed' (operator cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2).
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.coordination.OperatorCoordinatorHolder$LazyInitializedCoordinatorContext.failJob(OperatorCoordinatorHolder.java:651)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.coordination.RecreateOnResetOperatorCoordinator$QuiesceableContext.failJob(RecreateOnResetOperatorCoordinator.java:259)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinatorContext.failJob(SourceCoordinatorContext.java:432)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinatorContext.handleUncaughtExceptionFromAsyncCall(SourceCoordinatorContext.java:445)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ThrowableCatchingRunnable.run(ThrowableCatchingRunnable.java:42)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Failed to list subscribed topic partitions due to 
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.KafkaSourceEnumerator.checkPartitionChanges(KafkaSourceEnumerator.java:248)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.ExecutorNotifier.lambda$null$1(ExecutorNotifier.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ThrowableCatchingRunnable.run(ThrowableCatchingRunnable.java:40)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get metadata for topics [mytopic].
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.subscriber.KafkaSubscriberUtils.getTopicMetadata(KafkaSubscriberUtils.java:47)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.subscriber.TopicListSubscriber.getSubscribedTopicPartitions(TopicListSubscriber.java:52)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.KafkaSourceEnumerator.getSubscribedTopicPartitions(KafkaSourceEnumerator.java:233)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.ExecutorNotifier.lambda$notifyReadyAsync$2(ExecutorNotifier.java:80)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The AdminClient thread has exited. Call: describeTopics
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:165)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.subscriber.KafkaSubscriberUtils.getTopicMetadata(KafkaSubscriberUtils.java:44)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The AdminClient thread has exited. Call: describeTopics


below is the code piece i  am using to connect flink with kafka
 KafkaSource<String> source = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers("boostrap.server:32100")
                .setTopics(parameter.get("topics", "newtopic"))
                .setGroupId(parameter.get("group", "mygroup"))
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
                .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
                .setProperty("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
                .setProperty("ssl.truststore.location", "/opt/flink/kafkatruststore.jks")
                .setProperty("ssl.truststore.password", "changeit")
                .setProperty("ssl.keystore.location", "/opt/flink/kafkatruststore.jks")
                .setProperty("ssl.keystore.password", "changeit")
                .setProperty("sasl.mechanism", "SCRAM-SHA-256")
                .setProperty("sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"username\" password=\"password\";")
                .build();


        //read data from kafka
        DataStream<String> text = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka Source");



My kafka and my flink is deployed in kubernetes cluster. I am using ui to trigger job.

I cannot find any satisfactory resolution anywhere. Can anyone help me debug this issue.
Note my kafka is ssl secured.

Is it Ok that in logs your topic called [mytopic] but in your code you have topic with the name newtopic (.setTopics(parameter.get("topics", "newtopic"))) ?

@Niko I am taking topic from ParameterTool . In case parameter  "topics" is not passed then newtopic will be used.

Based on the message that you are receiving ("Failed to get metadata for topics ...") this typically indicates one of two things: either your specific topic does not exist or more likely, there's an issue with the related Kafka configuration for your source/sinks to ensure that the proper security settings are being used. If it's the latter, this means that Flink won't be able to talk to Kafka and will ultimately fail as you are seeing now.
Per the Kafka Security documentation, you may want to triple check that your appropriate truststore and security related configurations can be accessed as expected and available on the classpath. You should be able to review over the logs for your failing job to verify some of this (e.g. classpath, security settings, etc.). Depending on how you are running your Flink job, you might consider seeing if you can shell into the pod to verify everything is in the proper location (or that your Docker image, if applicable, has the proper files mounted in their respective locations).
